# How to convert k8s manifest files to helm chart with Helmify?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I have convertes my deployment.yaml to a helm char with helmify command and it seems ok. However in my ingress I have a parametric variable and the value for the variable is taken from an xml dictionary file. This value can be different for different environments (test, prod, development). I want this value to be read from the xml file and be put in the seperate values file for seperate environments. (like values-dev.yaml, values-uat.yaml) Is there a way to do this with helmify command? If not is there a way to do this with Python scripts? test_hostname is the value that helmify can't read because it is in an xml file. There are other values like this as well. The error is : error converting json to yaml.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: deploy-app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: {{ test_hostname }} 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: deploy-app-service
            port:
              number: 5000
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ test_hostname }}
    secretName: tls-secret
```

Answer (score 0):

Helm's [template functions](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/) include a set of [conversion functions](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions), but only to and from JSON and YAML.  There's no support in Helm to read or write XML files.

Depending on how much you know about the specific file structure and layout, it's possible to do some tricks, like using [regex functions](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#regular-expressions) to look for specific bits of markup.  XML's syntax doesn't quite lend itself to this, though: things like attributes and namespaces will make it hard to write a regex that correctly matches an XML namespace-qualified element.

Probably the best approach here would be to preprocess the XML file into a YAML or JSON file, which you can then pass to a `helm install -f` option as a values structure that you can access using the Helm `.Values` object.  There are several ways to do that, depending on where the XML file originally comes from and what technologies you have access to and knowledge of.  (It looks like you've already asked [a subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77794309/how-to-convert-xml-file-values-to-values-yaml-to-use-in-helm) on this topic.)